# How to persist to UmbracoDataContext

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco

I use Linq to Umbraco extensively for read only operations ie.

```
IEnumerable<Country> countries = MyContainer.Instance.Countries.Where(c => c.NodeName == currentLocation);
```

how would I set about doing some like

```
Country c = new Country();
c.Name "australia";

Instance.persist(c); for eg.
```

Ive always used the traditional form below but I'd like to know if people do writes with Linq 2 Umbraco and how that might be structured

```
DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias("Textpage"); 
User author = User.GetUser(0); 

Document doc = Document.MakeNew("My new document", dt, author, 1018);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, Linq2Umbraco is still purely read-only - see [this article](http://www.aaron-powell.com/understanding-linq-to-umbraco) for details. I see from [this thread](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/25954-Creating-nodes-with-linq2umbraco-not-possible) too that it is still the case.

Personally, I still use the same method as yourself.

Comment: I think you are correct. The link mentions something about CRUD being potentially available in UmbracoDataProvider however seems that its up to the dev to implement what they need.